# Web Chatting Application in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new to Django trying to develop a chatting web project and stuck. Can someone help me which approach I should use?
I want to pass textbox data to Python without changing URL and I am not able to pass it.
My Javascript code

```
$("#button").click(function(){
var msg = $('#textbox').val();  
$("<div class='user' id='user'>"+msg+"</div>").insertBefore('.insert_after');
$('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
```

I used this ajax code below. However I am not able to retrieve the result in views.py file

```
$('.ajaxProgress').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/bot/",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            message: $('#textbox').val()
        },
        success: function(json){
            $('#test').html(json.message);
            $('.ajaxProgress').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#textbox').val("");

    });
```

can someone please explain how can I use it in views.py. I am getting a Forbidden error of csrf_token,

Comment: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /chat/get    this is the error message which I am viewing after running the code.

Comment: as you mentioned you have forbidden error in `/chat/get`  then add snippet of that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with ajax call csfr token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489089/issue-with-ajax-call-csfr-token)

Answer (score 0):

In your js code there is small bug

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function(){
    //some code
    var msg = $('#textbox').val();  
    $('#textbox').val("");                 /*if you are assigning "" to textbox */
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/bot/",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true,
      data:{
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
          message: msg                                   /*then here you have to use msg*/
      },
      success: function(json){
        //further code
      }
    });
    $('#textbox').val("");
  });
});
```

and talking about **Forbidden error of csrf_token** you have to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895547/7647827) to resolve

refer working code [here](https://repl.it/@onkarsathe/BadReflectingMathematics)

Comment: Thank you Onk_r. I did put {{csrf_token }} inside my form tag ,    and added the python code .... However I am still getting the same error

Comment: I am getting an alert box with message as "errorForbidden" I refered success code from that working code which is passing this alert. Not sure why this message is appearing and in console "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)"  is displayed.

Comment: can you please connect with me and check if you can help

Comment: your url field in ajax is going wrong you just have to add path after `/` like `/bot/`

Comment: still same error in my machine . though I can see msg is properly pushed in your shared code .  Can I share my screen through app to show you the error ?

Comment: I lost the link can you please share the drive link again of working code

Answer (score 0):

Yeah many people receive this kind of error, put at the end of your html. If you have a `base.py` which all of your templates extend from, you can also put it in there. This solves the AJAX csrf_token issue. This is probably a duplicate answer, but I cannot find my other post with this code.

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script type="text/javascript">
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Edit: Found my other post.

Comment: I tried this and getting the same error. I think there is some issue in my settings if you can have a look via screen sharing it will be helpful.

Comment: Most likely it is in your settings. Would be great if you posted.

Comment: I am no sure if you helped me in rectifying the code.if yes Can you please share the drive link again